# How to migrate a wordpress website to new host?

Tags: wordpress, migration

So I am a university student and one of my main courses is web development.

For my final school work I have to make a website for a client. The client has a website on realwebsite.com (example) but he wants to completely modernize it. I can't have access to realwebsite.com yet, so I am making it on fakewebsite.com (example) using Wordpress (wordpress.org).

So let's say on fakewebsite.com I download paid themes, plugins etc. And when I finish, I want to transfer all the content of fakewebsite.com to realwebsite.com, what would be the best way to migrate all the content?
Would paid themes/plugins still work? Is it the best way to go about it?

Thank you

EDIT: I would also like to add that realwebsite.com is NOT a wordpress website

Comment: "I would also like to add that realwebsite.com is NOT a wordpress website" - But it _will_ be a WordPress site after the fact, right? So you are going to delete the existing site (backing it up, first), and replace it with the other site?